# What does $\Delta m_s$ mean in regard to meson and quark decays? And what are (syst) and (stat) in regard to margins of error?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, terminology, standard-model, error-analysis

From Wikipedia, B meson:

The neutral B mesons,
B0
and
B0
s, spontaneously transform into their own antiparticles and back. This phenomenon is called flavor oscillation. The existence of neutral B meson oscillations is a fundamental prediction of the Standard Model of particle physics. It has been measured in the
B0
–
B0
system to be about 0.496 / picoseconds,[1] and in the
B0
s–
B0
s system to be Δms = 17.77 ± 0.10 (stat) ± 0.07 (syst) / picosecond measured by CDF experiment at Fermilab.

And Wikipedia, Strange B meson:

Strange B mesons are noted for their ability to oscillate between matter and antimatter via a box-diagram with Δms = 17.77 ± 0.10 (stat) ± 0.07 (syst) ps−1 measured by CDF experiment at Fermilab.

Does the '0.496/picoseconds' and '17.77/picosecond' mean the oscillations occur every two picoseconds, and every 18 picoseconds, respectively?

What does 'delta m_s' mean?  Or $\Delta m_s$?

What is a 'box diagram', regarding (presumably) neutral particle oscillations?

What are (syst) and (stat)?  Something to do with differing margins of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic box Feynman diagram gets the name by its shape , for example it is needed for calculating [two photon interactions:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics)

[image: twophot]

The B oscillation  diagram has complicated labeling of the virtually  exchanged quarks, using interactions so that a quark  becomes an antiquark

[image: Bosci]

> [Two Feynman box diagrams](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Two-Feynman-box-diagrams-showing-two-different-ways-of-exchanging-virtual-particles_fig33_254469182) showing two different ways of exchanging virtual particles which allow the B and B_0 s mesons to become their anti-particles

$Δ(m_s)$  is the error on the mass of the s  quark. Errors mean that the mass value has been taken from experimental measurements in order to calculate the diagrams.Experimental measurements come with two types of errors, statistical and systematic. The statistical depends on the number of particles used to extract the value, usually from a histogram of the mass. Systematic is the error induced by the experimental setup and analysis and is estimated in various ways depending on the analysis of the experimental results.